# Adding a sorting alogrithm animation crashes the browser d3.js

Tags: javascript, typescript, sorting, d3.js

Welcome , I tring to animate diffrent kinds of sorting alogrithms for now i want to setup animation with first that is bubble sort.My problem is when i click the start button to run the animation the whole browser crushes I am aware that this is triggered by the sorting function but I have no idea what to do so that there is no such problem.

this is my code for drawingVisualisation

```
import * as d3 from "d3";

const drawVisualization = (data: number[]) => {
  const margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40 };
  const width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
  const height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // If it is .visualization del it first
  d3.select(".visualization").selectAll("rect").remove();
  d3.select(".visualization").select("svg").remove();

  const svg = d3
    .select(".visualization")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  const rects = svg.selectAll("rect").data(data).enter().append("rect");

  rects
    .attr("x", (_d, i) => i * (width / data.length))
    .attr("y", (d) => height - d)
    .attr("width", () => width / data.length - 1)
    .attr("height", (d) => d)
    .on("mouseover", function (_d, i) {
      d3.select(this.parentElement)
        .append("text")
        .text(i)
        .attr(
          "x",
          () =>
            data.indexOf(i) * (width / data.length) + width / data.length / 2
        )
        .attr("y", height - i - 20)
        .attr("font-size", "14px")
        .attr("fill", "blue")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

      d3.select(this).style("opacity", 0.85);
    })
    .on("mouseleave", function () {
      d3.select(this.parentElement).select("text").remove();

      d3.select(this).style("opacity", 1);
    });

  const startButton = document.querySelector(
    ".run-sorting-btn"
  ) as HTMLButtonElement;

  startButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < data.length - i - 1; j++) {
        if (data[j] > data[j + 1]) {
          const temp = data[j];
          data[j] = data[j + 1];
          data[j + 1] = temp;

          // Animate the movement here
          rects
            .data(data)
            .transition()
            .delay((d, i) => i * 50)
            .duration(500)
            .attr("x", (_d, i) => i * (width / data.length));
        }
      }
    }
  });
};

export default drawVisualization;
```

And  from this function this is the trouble maker:
Edit i changed the code from `.data(data)` to `.data(data[j],data[j+1]`
but still have performance issues

```
 const startButton = document.querySelector(
    ".run-sorting-btn"
  ) as HTMLButtonElement;

  startButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < data.length - i - 1; j++) {
        if (data[j] > data[j + 1]) {
          const temp = data[j];
          data[j] = data[j + 1];
          data[j + 1] = temp;

          // Animate the movement here
          rects
            .data([data[j], data[j + 1]])
            .transition()
            .delay((d, i) => i * 50)
            .duration(500)
            .attr("x", (_d, i) => i * (width / data.length));
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: What's the size of the data? Also, did you mean "crashes"?

Comment: yes sorry crashes i edit it right away

Comment: data is not big user can choose from 50 - 500 numbers , numbers are shuffled with fisher-yates shuffle

Comment: what does the line after `// Animate the movement here` do? Does it reshuffle the entire rects array? That could be very expensive and cause the browser to become unresponsive. Also, the delay on the rects is only i * 50, which seems wrong because it doesn't take into account the inner loop.

Comment: I so instead puting all data i should put only two elements changing like `[data[j], data[j + 1]]` here

Comment: Yeah, that would probably be much more performant. Also, try increasing the delay to something like 2000-3000 between element swaps and seeing if it still crashes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250950/discussion-between-aspectofthenoob-and-ivonak). (auto-generated)